# Error in writing function in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I've used this snippet code to create a function to export tables in JSON format in PostgreSQL. But the problem occurs when I wanted to use dynamic path for storing my output JSON file as the input argument of the function. When I replace the 'path' variable with something like 'c:\myfile.json' it doesn't have any error. What's wrong with path variable? Thanks.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_Export2JSON(tableName TEXT, fields TEXT, path TEXT)
RETURNS VOID AS 
$$
Copy(SELECT row_to_json(fc)
FROM ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As     features
FROM ( SELECT 'Feature' As type, ST_AsGeoJSON(hp.geom)::json As geometry, row_to_json((select l from(select fields) as l)) As properties 
FROM tableName As hp ) As f )  As fc) to path;
$$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT
```

And this is the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "path"
LINE 7:  FROM tableName As hp ) As f )  As fc) to path;
                                              ^
```

Comment: I think you need pgplsql here with `execute fromat()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [plpgsql dynamic command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN), example:

```
create or replace function example(path text)
returns void language plpgsql as $$
begin
    -- instead of
    -- copy (select 1) to path;
    -- use:
    execute format('copy (select 1) to %L', path);
end $$;
```

Comment: Yeah, it works. I also changed the table to %I and fields to %s. Thanks, @klin.